# Word for experiencing a sense of humorous satisfaction in a shared problem

Tags: single-word-requests

You're having a problem with something. Someone shares a humorous anecdote about a time they experienced the same problem, and you feel better because of it.

> "Maybe this will cheer you up, in a ______ kind of way."

There's a single word for this, and it's on the tip of my tongue, but I'm drawing a complete blank. I can't even conjure up a synonym. It's a bit like "a problem shared is a problem halved", except it's more about experiencing a dark humour.

Someone help me out here?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147222/discussion-on-question-by-polynomial-word-for-experiencing-a-sense-of-humorous-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you’re thinking of *perverse*:

> *Maybe this will cheer you up, in a perverse kind of way.*

> **perverse**, *adj.*
> **1.**
> **a.** Of a person, action, etc.: going or disposed to go against what is reasonable, logical, expected, or required; contrary, fickle,
> irrational.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Comment: It wasn't what Poly was really asking for but it is in use and does fit the bill. The 'shared' part is implicit: the speaker and listener both understand the speaker isn't _really_ calling the other person perverse but acknowledging that while _they_ can find the humor in it, _sure_ not everyone would see it the same way.

Comment: This fits the question’s specific example sentence excellently; on the other hand it doesn’t fit the description in the question title at all — in general, it doesn’t carry any connotations of “humorous satisfaction in a shared problem”.  (Not criticising this as an answer, but just noting the point so that later readers don’t misunderstand and assume this can mean what the title describes.)

Comment: @PLL — OP refers to “dark humor.” Cheering someone up with a tale of misfortune is a form of dark humor, which is a perversion of your standard humor. Dark humor works here because the misfortune is shared by both parties.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this will cheer you up, in a **commiserative** kind of way.

> ***commiserative*** (*adj.*)
> Feeling or expressing commiseration, compassion, pity or sympathy.
> [[Wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commiserative)

Answer (score 4):

In Christopher Marlowe's play "Doctor Faustus," Faustus asks Mephistopheles (a "senior devil", Hell's equivalent of Heaven's Archangel Gabriel) why he wants to increase the number of souls in Hell. Mephistophiles replies in Latin ***Solamen miseris socios habuisse doloris***, which could be translated as ***It is a comfort to the wretched to have companions in grief.***

At some later point that got boiled down to the far more pithy ***Misery loves company***. Google Books seem to have [hundreds of instances of that](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20misery%20loves%20company%22) - mostly in "air quotes" and/or hyphenated. For example...

> *While we found some solace **in a “misery loves company” sort of way** at the workshop, our new compadres began to see progress while we were still stuck in the storm.*

Comment: Definitely not it. I'm looking for a single word.

Comment: If there *was* a single word with any currency, I don't think I'd have found so many published instances of "**a misery loves company**" (with the article, so they'll nearly all be ***adjectival*** uses). It's only now you're making me look again that I'm taken aback to see how many there are - it's literally *hundreds!*

Answer (score 3):

*Morbid* fits the cadence and sentiment of that sentence.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/morbid) gives:

> ***morbid***, *(adj.)*
> [disapproving]
>
> too interested in unpleasant subjects, especially death:
> *a morbid fascination with death*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Schadenfreude" is the word you're looking for?

It refers to a particular *kind* of dark-humor appreciation, but maybe it applies here, since you mentioned *"having a problem with something"*.  It's a loan word, from German.

> Noun: **Schadenfreude**
>
> Delight in another person's misfortune
>
> Type of: delectation, delight

https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=Schadenfreude

Comment: Not schadenfreude. (I mentioned this in the question comments)

Comment: I see. Comments don't count. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

**Mutual** (All definitions from Merriam-Webster)

> 1c: shared in common

> 2: characterized by intimacy

**Joint:**

> 2b: shared by or affecting two or more

**Shared:**

> 1: used, done, belonging to, or experienced by two or more individuals

**Sympathetic:** (although this is no longer the most common meaning)

> 1: existing or operating through an affinity, interdependence, or mutual association

You couldn’t say “in a common sort of way,” without being misunderstood, but something like “common grief” would work here as well.

Answer (score -2):

*Hubristic* might fit your purpose.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hubristic) gives the adjective:

> too proud:
> He has a hubristic resistance to admitting he is wrong.

Comment: That means something completely different.